# How Get a list of current running APP in Android

Tags: android

I want to use the ActivityManager to get a list of current APPs and return the  newest process` name to the system clipboard.Just like this

```
 protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Amanager=(ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo App=null;
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> RunningTasks;
        try {
            RunningTasks = Amanager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            App = RunningTasks.get(0);
        }catch (final Exception e){Log.d(TAG, "List ERROR");}
        if(App!=null) {
            String result =App.processName;
            contentText.setText(result);;
            Clipboard.setText(result);
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "COMPONENT ERROR");
        }
    }
```

But when running at the Simulator, some errors occured:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{//the absolute address}:

Comment: can you post your MainActivity code here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
 {
   Log.i("App-Package","" + procInfos.get(i).processName);
}
```

This may helps you

Comment: So the newest one may be the proInfos.get(0)?

Answer (score 2):

You code is perfectly fine. You are getting this exception because your `contentText` is null. Make sure you're referencing it correctly.